# Is "by being pressed" in the following is correct ? "Clay is deformed by being pressed "

Tags: passive-voice

Although I think "Clay is deformed **when pressed** " is better than  "Clay is deformed **by being pressed**", I would like to know whether the latter is grammatically correct and sounds natural.

Comment: I assume you meant ***clay***, not ***cray***. Both your suggestions are "grammatical", but they don't sound very "natural". Idiomatically, native speakers would normally just use Simple Present rather than Present Perfect: *Clay **deforms** when pressed*.

Comment: Your rewrite suggests (though it does not entail) that the only way or best way of deforming clay is to press it, which is probably not what the sentence intends to say.

Comment: @StoneyB: I think there are some subtleties involved here. *Clay bricks are hardened by being baked in a kiln* works fine for me (and so does *Clay bricks harden when baked in a kiln*). But *Unfired clay bricks deteriorate by being left out in the rain* sounds pretty weird - I'm guessing that's because ***by*** implies *deliberate, purposeful* action leading to a *desired* result, but there's no such implication (or problem) with *Unfired clay bricks deteriorate **when** left out in the rain*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yeah. *By* generally answers the question "How is clay deformed?", *when* generally answers "What happens to clay when...?"

Comment: @StoneyB: My *deteriorate* examples don't really work with "present perfect" (presumably because it's intransitive), but there's also the matter of differentiating between *How **is** clay deformed?* and *How **does** clay deform?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your sentences 1) is that there is no reference to the state of the clay,usually only *wet* clay can be deformed; 2) deformation is usually used to describe a shape change which is not intended, e.g. "the body of the car was *deformed* in the accident collision".

Your first sentence

> Clay is deformed when pressed

means that clay will change shape when an external source is applied.

Your second sentence might be better described as

> Clay is molded ***by*** being pressed

since "molding" is an intended action to create a specific shape.

[image]
<sub>(source: [konterragroup.net](http://www.konterragroup.net/admin/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/potters-wheel-58557_640.jpg))</sub>

"Throwing" clay is usually though of as "molding" clay, not "deforming" clay.